# Unexpected token in st.mainloop in Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

```
def billing(): # to create bills for customer-------------------------------------------------------------BILLING system
    global c, cur, apt, flag, t, name, name1, add, st, names, qty, sl, qtys, vc_id, n, namee, lb1
    m_bill=make_bill()
    t=0
    vc_id=''
    names=[]
    qty=[]
    sl=[]
    n=[]
    qtys=['']*10
    cur.execute("select *from med")
    for i in cur:
        n.append(i[1])
    c.commit()
    if flag=='st':
        st.destroy()
    else:
        apt.destroy()
    flag='st'
    st=Tk()
    st.title('BILLING SYSTEM')
    Label(st,text='-'*48+'BILLING SYSTEM'+'-'*49).grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=7)
    Label(st,text='Enter Name: ').grid(row=1,column=0)
    name1=Entry(st)
    name1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    Label(st,text='Enter Address: ').grid(row=2,column=0)
    add=Entry(st)
    add.grid(row=2, column=1)
    Label(st,text="Value Id (if available)").grid(row=3, column=0)
    vc_id=Entry(st)
    vc_id.grid(row=3, column=1)
    Button(st,text='Check V.C.', command=blue).grid(row=4, column=0)
    Label(st,text='-'*115).grid(row=6, column=0,columnspan=7)
    Label(st,text='SELECT PRODUCT',width=25,relief='ridge').grid(row=7, column=0)
    Label(st,text=' RACK  QTY LEFT     COST          ',width=25,relief='ridge').grid(row=7, column=1)
    Button(st,text='Add to bill',width=15,command=append2bill).grid(row=8, column=6)
    Label(st,text='QUANTITY',width=20,relief='ridge').grid(row=7, column=5)
    qtys=Entry(st)
    qtys.grid(row=8,column=5)
    refresh()
    Button(st,width=15,text='Main Menu', command=main_menu).grid(row=1,column=6)
    Button(st,width=15,text='Refresh Stock', command=refresh).grid(row=3,column=6)
    Button(st,width=15,text='Reset Bill', command=billing).grid(row=4,column=6)
    Button(st,width=15,text='Buy', command=lambda:send_mail(m_bill)).grid(row=5,column=6)
    Button(st,width=15,text='Save Bill', command=make_bill().grid(row=7,column=6)
    st.mainloop()
```

In the function above, I am getting a weird error in the last line as `st.mainloop` as invalid syntax. st.mainloop is an inbuilt function provide by Tkinter to run the GUI in loop. I am just pulling my hair on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. There was a missing parenthesis in  `Button(st,width=15,text='Save Bill', command=make_bill().grid(row=7,column=6))`

Answer (score 0):

Your button should look like this:

```
Button(st, width=15, text='Save Bill', command=make_bill).grid(row=7, column=6)
```

So your button was not missing a parenthesis but actually had one too many.